# show that n is a power of 2 given it satisfies a combinatorial property

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math, generating-functions

> Let $\{a_1,\cdots, a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,\cdots, b_n\}$ be two distinct sets of positive integers such that any integer can be written as $a_i+a_j$ with $i\neq j$ in exactly as many ways as it can be written as $b_i+b_j$ with $i\neq j$. Show that $n$ is a power of $2$.

It might be useful to use generating functions to count useful objects for this problem. Let $f(x) = \sum_{i} x^{a_i}, g(x) = \sum_{i} x^{b_i}.$ Note that $f(x)^2 - f(x^2) = g(x)^2-g(x^2).$ To show this, we have that $f(x)^2 = \sum_{i,j} x^{a_i + a_j}$ and $f(x^2) = \sum_{i} x^{2a_i}$, so $f(x)^2 - f(x^2)$ has as the coefficient of $x^k$ the number of ways to write $k$ as $a_i+a_j$ with $i\neq j$. Similarly, the coefficient of $x^k$ in $g(x)^2-g(x^2)$ counts the number of ways to write k as a sum $b_i+b_j$ where $i\neq j$. Hence by the problem's assumption $f(x)^2 - f(x^2) = g(x)^2-g(x^2)\tag{1}$ We now need to conclude that $n$ is a power of 2 somehow. Suppose not, and write $n=2^k q$ for some odd $q>1.$ We need to derive a contradiction somehow (likely by showing that $(1)$ does not hold).

Comment: This is an amazing question, I'll admit that I'm shocked that no one has touched it. +1, and I think you're in the right direction but I can't proceed further either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is a paraphrased solution of user fattypiggy123 in this [AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1320187p7111012).

Rewrite $f(x)^2 - f(x^2) = g(x)^2-g(x^2)$ as
$$f(x^2)-g(x^2)=f(x)^2-g(x)^2=(f(x)-g(x))(f(x)+g(x)).\tag{*}$$
Now write $f(x)-g(x)=(x-1)^kP(x)$ with $k \geq 0$ such that $P(1)\neq 0$. Then $(*)$ gives
$$
(x^2-1)^kP(x^2)=(x-1)^kP(x)(f(x)+g(x)),
$$
simplifying to
$$
(x+1)^kP(x^2)=P(x)(f(x)+g(x))\tag{**}.
$$
Finally plugging $x=1$ into $(**)$ we get $2^kP(1)=P(1)(f(1)+g(1))$, and since $P(1)\neq 0$, we have $2^k=f(1)+g(1)$. But since $f,g$ are polynomials with exactly $n$ terms and each of them with coefficient $1$, we have $f(1)=g(1)=n$. So $2n=2^k$ and finally $n=2^{k-1}$.

**Note:** In fact $k \geq 1$, since $f(1)-g(1)=n-n=0$ and so $x-1 \mid f(x)-g(x)$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you check out [this functional equations question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549625/show-that-fx-x-where-forall-x-y-in-mathbbr-fxfyxy-y1fx) if you have time?

Comment: @user3379 You can search mathematical expressions using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/), there is a lot to find especially for functional equations.